# o.s.d.jpa.repository.query.NamedQuery : Did not find named query ... in multi module project

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have multi module project (*.war).

It's an entry point in app.

```java
@SpringBootConfiguration
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"....dao.repository"})
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"....dao.model"})
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"..."})
public class ApsTtsApplication
        extends SpringBootServletInitializer
        implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    private static final Logger LOGGER  = LoggerFactory.getLogger( ApsTtsApplication.class );

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        LOGGER.info("Start an application...");

        SpringApplication.run(ApsTtsApplication.class, args);
    }


    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {

        LOGGER.info("There is building the web application!");

        return builder.sources(ApsTtsApplication.class);
    }
}
```

model

- IdMainForEntities

```java
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class IdMainForEntities {

    @Id
    @GenericGenerator(name="system-uuid", strategy = "uuid")
    @GeneratedValue(generator="system-uuid")
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private String ID;

    public IdMainForEntities() {
    }

    public String getID() {
        return ID;
    }

    public void setID(String ID) {
        this.ID = ID;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        IdMainForEntities that = (IdMainForEntities) o;
        return Objects.equals(ID, that.ID);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(ID);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "IdMainEntity{" +
                "ID='" + ID + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

- MessageLog

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "MESSAGESLOG")
public class MessageLog extends IdMainForEntities {
...

    @Column(name = "MSG_OWNER_ID")
    @Size(message = "MSG_OWNER_ID{MessagesLog.size}", max = 32)
    private String msgOwnerId;

  public MessageLog() {
    }

  public String getMsgOwnerId() {
        return msgOwnerId;
    }

    public void setMsgOwnerId(String msgOwnerId) {
        this.msgOwnerId = msgOwnerId;
    }

....


}
```

- MessagesLogReadRepository

```java
public interface MessagesLogReadRepository extends CrudRepository <MessageLog, String> {

    Optional <MessageLog> findByMsgOwnerId(String msgOwnerId);

    MessageLog findMessageLogByMsgOwnerId(String msgOwnerId);

    Optional <MessageLog> findByDocument(String documentId);

}
```

Only standard methods can be called from this repository : **findById ()**, etc.

But named queries is not found.

> 18-03-2020 08:49:39.531 DEBUG 8660   o.s.d.j.r.query.JpaQueryFactory
>   : Looking up query for method findByMsgOwnerId  18-03-2020
>   08:49:39.547 DEBUG 8660   o.s.d.jpa.repository.query.NamedQuery    :
>   Looking up named query MessageLog.findByMsgOwnerId  18-03-2020
>   08:49:39.547 DEBUG 8660   o.h.e.t.internal.TransactionImpl         :
>   On TransactionImpl creation,
>   JpaCompliance#isJpaTransactionComplianceEnabled == false  18-03-2020
>   08:49:39.547 DEBUG 8660   o.s.d.jpa.repository.query.NamedQuery    :
>   Did not find named query MessageLog.findByMsgOwnerId

```java
@Override
    public MessageLogDto getByMsgOwnerId(String msgOwnerId) {

 if(msgOwnerId == null) throw  new MessagesLogException(paramNotNull);

/*It's null*/
        Optional<MessageLog> byMsgOwnerId = this.messagesLogReadRepository.findByMsgOwnerId("8a00844170d829040170d82c670b00");
        MessageLog messageLog = byMsgOwnerId.orElse(new MessageLog());
     /*It's OK*/
        Optional<MessageLog> byId = this.messagesLogReadRepository.findById("8a00844170d829040170d82c670b0003");

        return transformEntityToDto(messageLog);

       }
```

Update

```java
public interface MessagesLogReadRepository extends JpaRepository<MessageLog, String> {


    @Query(value = "SELECT * from messageslog where MSG_OWNER_ID = ?1", nativeQuery = true )
    Optional <MessageLog> findRowByMsgOwnerId(String msgOwnerId);

...
```

...**extends JpaRepository**

But, It doesn't solve the problem.

I don't have any mistakes. I only get null, but the requested row is in the table, that 's for sure.

does anyone have any ideas about this?

Why ?

Comment: extends `JpaRepository` instead of `CrudRepository`

Comment: why using so many annotations when @SpringBootApplication is just a meta annotation of all those you have defined

Comment: EnableJPARepository and EnableEntity scan is auto enabled by default when jpa is in the classapth

Comment: the project is a multi -module one . that's why there are a lot of annotations. I removed the unnecessary annotations.

Comment: I don't know if @ SpringBootApplication will be able to scan the modules themselves

Answer (score 1):

**Solution**

The field we were working with had a data type **CHAR(32 byte)**. We changed this type to **VARCHAR(32 byte)** into a table database of Oracle.

Now, Spring can build named query fine.

The project on older versions of Spring worked like this ...(**CHAR(32 byte)**)

I don't understand why so.